# NetLogo nothing named SCREEN-SIZE-X has been defined

Tags: netlogo, screen-size

i'm new using NetLogo and I'm trying to learn it using the 'Hello World' model found on the net. I'm running NetLogo 5.2 on Mac OS X (Yosemite). When I try to set the turtles randomly, in this way

```
setxy random screen-size-x random screen-size-y
```

I get this error: Nothing named SCREEN-SIZE-X has been defined

screen-size-x appears in capitalization and so i get an error on this built-in function. Can anyone help me? Thank you

This is the NetLogo code I'm using:

```
globals [buttons]           ; Global variables

to setup                    ; Initializes model for new run.
    set-default-shape turtles "circle" ; Turtles are circles
    clear-all                          ; Reset turtles and patches
    set buttons 500                    ; Set number of buttons to 500
    create-turtles (buttons)           ; Create "buttons" number of turtles
    ask turtles [setup-turtles]        ; Initialize each turtle
end

to setup-turtles            ; Called for each turtle during setup
    setxy random screen-size-x random screen-size-y ; Set our x,y randomly
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `screen-size-x` and `screen-size-y` are NetLogo history. You can use `max-pxcor`, `max-pycor` and `min-pxcor`, `min-pycor` to get the world borders or `world-width` and `world-height` to get just the size.

To get a random position there are `random-xcor` and `random-ycor`.

```
to setup-turtles  
  setxy random-xcor random-ycor
end
```

Comment: That's right! Thank you. No guide i've been reading reported these new functions.

Comment: There is a lot of out-of-date stuff out there, just floating around the Internet. I would suggest using http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/resources.shtml to locate learning resources.